# magento homepage and other pages headers are different

Tags: html, magento

In magento backend, I though no matter homepage or other pages should use the same header file. However, when I change the logo picture for header in backend, only homepage's header picture was changed successfully, other pages are not showing the picture correctly.
Basically what I did is, there are two rows in header, so I put half of the logo on left of the first row and and the other half of the logo on left of the second row, so it seems like a bigger logo.
[homepage pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo0Qc.png)
what it should be
[catalog and product view page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6S6y.png)
in catalog and product view page(bottom part of the logo is not changed)

in secondary catalog page, the upper part of the logo is missing, and bottom part of the logo is not changed.

code path: design/frontend/theme/template/page/html/header.phtml

```
<div class="header-top">
        <a href="http://scifitoys.com.au/"><img src="media/images/logoUp.jpg" style="width:500px;height:60px;"></a>
        <div class="header-top-search-wrapper">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
            <?php /*TODO: ?><a class="advanced-search-link" href="<?php echo Mage::getURL('') ?>catalogsearch/advanced/"><?php print $this->__('Advanced Search') ?></a><?php */?>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
        <?php if ($tmp_html = $this->getChildHtml('i_block_header_top_help')): ?> <?php //Predefined CMS block ?>
            <div class="header-top-help-wrapper"><?php echo $tmp_html; ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($tmp_html = $this->getChildHtml('i_block_header_top_links')): ?> <?php //Predefined CMS block ?>
            <div class="header-top-links-wrapper"><?php echo $tmp_html; ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    //<?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
    <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="media/images/logoDown.jpg" style="width:500px;height:60px;"></a></h1>
    //<?php else:?>
   // <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
   // <?php endif?>

    <div class="header-left">
        <?php if ($tmp_html = $this->getChildHtml('i_block_header_contact')): ?> <?php //Predefined CMS block ?>
            <div class="header-contact-wrapper"><?php echo $tmp_html; ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($tmp_html = $this->getChildHtml('i_block_header_banner')): ?> <?php //Predefined CMS block ?>
            <div class="header-banner-wrapper"><?php echo $tmp_html; ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div> <!-- end: header-left -->

    <div class="header-right">
        <div class="header-right-secondary">
            <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome() ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="user-menu">

            <?php // Show custom link, if enabled ?>
            <?php if ($themeHelper->getCfg('header/links_custom_link_enabled')): ?>
                <?php
                    $_customLinkPath = $themeHelper->getCfg('header/links_custom_link_path');
                    $_customLinkAnchor = $themeHelper->getCfg('header/links_custom_link_anchor');
                    $_customLinkTitle = $themeHelper->getCfg('header/links_custom_link_title');
                ?>
                <ul>
                    <li class="user-menu-item user-menu-custom">
                        <a href="<?php echo Mage::getURL('') . $_customLinkPath; ?>/" title="<?php echo $_customLinkTitle; ?>"><?php echo $_customLinkAnchor; ?></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <?php endif?>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>

            <?php // If customer is not logged in: show "Sign Up" link, if enabled ?>
            <?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() == false): ?>
                <?php if ($themeHelper->getCfg('header/links_signup_enabled')): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="user-menu-item user-menu-signup">
                            <a href="<?php echo Mage::getURL('') ?>customer/account/create/" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up') ?></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif?>
            <?php endif?>

            <ul>
                <li id="mini-cart" class="user-menu-item user-menu-cart">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_sidebar') ?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end: header-right -->
```

The above code is for header's part. 
I'm quite confused, shouldn't all pages use the same header file? why they appear differently?
Thank you

Comment: In your code static scourse url in image tag.

Comment: Yes, it should be a dynamic one. and it will be small logo. But I can't use static url here? That's the reason??

Comment: I change the condition for if on about line 16. Though I commented the code. So I uncomment it, and change condition to see if this website is the one I want. (This code is applied to multiple websites.) So it works now for homepage and main categories. but for secondary category, it still can't get the images.

Comment: OK... I know. I think it is because I shouldn't use static url here.

Comment: Yes here you have to use dynamic url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the problem now. 
The reason why secondary categories can't get the image is because the url is hostname/categoryName/image.jpg
So the url is not valid here anymore. Should have use dynamic url here.